# SwiftUI drag gesture jump

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, drag, gesture

Swift 5, iOS 13.x

I got this super simple app that lets me drag a view around by using the offset with SwiftUI, and when it stops I reset the offset and the position. Works well the first time, but each time I go back to drag it again it jumps when I release the button. How can I fix this ... I found something that mentioned insets? Is it related to insets?

Now I know this answers the question with some different code [kontiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488175/swiftui-gesture-and-offset-are-not-working-as-intended) but I want to understand what is wrong with my solution.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var dragOffset = CGSize.zero
  @State var position:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Circle()
      .frame(width: 12, height: 128, alignment: .center)
    }.offset(x: self.dragOffset.width, y: self.dragOffset.height)
    .gesture(DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
    .onChanged({ ( value ) in
      self.dragOffset = CGSize(width: value.translation.width, height: value.translation.height)
    })
    .onEnded { ( value ) in
      self.dragOffset = .zero
      self.position = value.location
    }
).position(position)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut says that you are likely dealing with an issue that has to do with the SafeArea EdgeInsets. It's hard to tell. If you're interested, I did two videos on the drag gesture and the tap gesture to create views when you tap and to drag them if you tap on a previously generated view:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3mzLhPfLaE&list=PLEHYNiA7SPcP9zzQYHAN1T27w4cwG_f5i

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0F5ZuJgzoY&list=PLEHYNiA7SPcP9zzQYHAN1T27w4cwG_f5i&index=2

Comment: It is a great answer and I watched both videos and learnt something new into the bargain, will try and investigate safeareaEdgeInsets you mentioned,